# Xcode says "Uncommitted Changes" Whenever I try to git pull or push

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore, pull

I am using git in my projects, whenever I try to pull from Xcode I get "Uncommitted Changes" and it prevents me from pulling/pushing.
I try to commit and find one file with extension *.xcuserstate, this file is modified whenever I open/scroll into any project file in Xcode. That leaves me no option but to do a single commit that contains that file, which fill the git commit logs with meaningless commits.

Is this there is a way to stop this behavior?

I tried to put *.xcuserstate and xcuserdata into git ignore but that caused Xcode to crash every time I try to pull.

This happens with Xcode 4.2 and 4.3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally you don't want to put the `*.xcuserstate` and `*.xcuserdata` files into your Git repository. These files aren't really part of your project, but are just a place where Xcode stores its local information that is helpful when reloading your project.

You can fix this by using:

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate *.xcuserdata
```

and then committing the result. This will remove those files from the repository without removing them from your working directory.

Comment: I tried to put them in gitignore but Xcode crash when I try to pull, does this happen with you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Is Xcode running when you pull? Perhaps try closing Xcode first.

Comment: I will try it with my team and accept the answer if it worked OK.

Comment: I tried your solution and .xcuserstate files are now untracked.
Everytime I try to pull from Xcode it crashes.
The only solution stopped it from crashing is to add and commit .xcuserstate files again...

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to stop track them at all ? It is pretty annoying that every time you commit "something in the interface of Xcode" changes... And this file changes...

Answer (score 2):

If this is a settings file which is different for every developer, you probably don't need to version control it, just remove it from Git.

If that is not an option, you can `Git Stash Save` your changes before pulling and `Git Stash pop` to apply them again.

Comment: I tried to put them in gitignore but Xcode crash when I try to pull, does this happen with you, did you try that method?

Comment: No, personally I never put configuration files under source control. Did you try to stash them instead?