# Cannot push, pull or merge git. "Working copy has uncommited changes"

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository, bitbucket

I have recently set up a git repository on bitbucket, and have added an old project onto it. I have committed and pushed a change as a test, but now I face this problem.

Each time I try to Pull, Push, or Merge I get this error message:

[image: The working copy "" has uncommitted changes.]

"The working copy 'Project_Name' has uncommitted changes".

And I have committed this change several times:

[image: The file seems to be named: User Interface State]

---

**EDIT**: I did 'git status' and got the following:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Crunch.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/Neil.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

---

Help would be greatly appreciated, SirKaydian

Comment: U have checked using git status that u have no uncommited changes right?

Comment: How would I do that? I did "Refresh Status", still nothing.

Comment: I suggest navigating to the root of your project in a command prompt and doing a 'git status'.  Alot of Git UIs are unreliable and won't tell you about unstaged files.  You might have to do a 'git add .' to stage new files that have yet to be committed.

Comment: Alright, I did the 'git status'. Check out the post. Also the `git add .` didn't do anything

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step 1:

```
git rm --cached ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Step 2:

```
git commit -m "Removed file that shouldn't be tracked"
```

Comment: I had tried this but not succeeded, can you help to achieve this?

Comment: What is this address?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, turns out I just had to make a comment

```
//THIS IS A TEST
```

And commit that. Now it works fine. This must have just been some strange bug.

Thanks for the help though, SirKaydian

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the answer when you are able to.

Comment: :-) Have a great time programming on the worlds best platform :-)

Comment: where did you make this comment?  please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with the `.xcuserstate` file, but it sounds like a user-specific file.  Generally user-specific files have no business in source control.  They change frequently, generally are binary and thus difficult to diff, and aren't helpful to other users.  Try closing down your IDE then running the commands or try adding this file name to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

```
git push <remote> localbranch --force.
```

Do not use the --force flag unless you’re absolutely sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate *.xcuserdata
```

Run the above command. Then commit, then push.

See here: [Xcode says "Uncommitted Changes" Whenever I try to git pull or push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173261/xcode-says-uncommitted-changes-whenever-i-try-to-git-pull-or-push)

You may need to run them separately :

```
git rm --cached *.xcuserstate
git rm --cached *.xcuserdata
```