# Xcode 4.6 won't let me push my project to a git repo

Tags: git, repository, push, commit, xcode4.6

I've started a new project in Xcode (a command line app using C++), and am encountering a problem I haven't had in my other projects: I can successfully commit files, but can't push them to the repo, under the pretence that the changes haven't been committed yet (which they have).

There's a question here with [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910228/cannot-push-pull-or-merge-git-working-copy-has-uncommited-changes), but none of the answers there solve my problem. In the organizer, under the remote repo I've set up, the commits show up, comments and all, but I still can't manage to push them to the remote repo.

EDIT: I've seen another question where the issue was that the asker was trying to push to a non-bare repository. My repo was completely bare.

EDIT 2: I've managed to commit and push without any hiccups from the UNIX terminal. Still can't figure out how to do it directly from Xcode, though.

Has anyone experienced this problem, and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the command line `git` to commit and push the changes to my remote repo, I restarted my computer. Now, everything seems to work fine.