# The working copy “project_name” has uncommitted changes using bitbucket

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bitbucket

Xcode is suddenly and unexpectedly giving me the following message.

The working copy (project name) has uncommitted changes. Commit or discard the changes and try again.

Never had that before. How do I get rid of it or can I?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: are you using `git`  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot push, pull or merge git. "Working copy has uncommited changes"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910228/cannot-push-pull-or-merge-git-working-copy-has-uncommited-changes)

Comment: @Lion, No. Bitbucket :)